# ReactJS - Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null

Tags: reactjs

Stuck with sample code from book learning React. Code below throwing `Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of 'Card'.`. Checked SO (there are couple with similar issues) but I couldn't figure out what's wrong here.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import CheckList from './CheckList';

class Card extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card">
                <div className="card__title">{this.props.title}</div>
                <div className="card__details">
                    {this.props.description}
                    <CheckList cardId={this.props.id} tasks={this.props.tasks} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

CheckList.js

```
class CheckList extends Component{
    render(){
          let tasks = this.props.tasks.map((task)=>(
            <li className="checklist__task">
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={task.done} />
                {task.name}

            </li>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="checklist">
                <ul>{tasks}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: seems works fine - https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/34262/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to export `CheckList`

Change your class definition to:

```
export default class CheckList extends Component{
```

Comment: Aha.  This is it. As soon as I did `export default CheckList;` this worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as following.

from

```js
class CheckList extends Component{
    render(){
          let tasks = this.props.tasks.map((task)=>(
            <li className="checklist__task">
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={task.done} />
                {task.name}

            </li>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="checklist">
                <ul>{tasks}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export class CheckList
```

to

```js
export default class CheckList extends Component{
    render(){
          let tasks = this.props.tasks.map((task)=>(
            <li className="checklist__task">
                <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={task.done} />
                {task.name}

            </li>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="checklist">
                <ul>{tasks}</ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```